# Why would jps (the java VM lister) give different answers in cygwin than from cmd.exe?

Tags: java, cygwin

When I run jps in cygwin, I only see jps itself listed:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/tools/java/jdk-11.0.9.1+1/bin/jps.exe
10712 Jps
```

Running the same command from a command prompt shows all my current java processes:

```
C:\>c:\tools\java\jdk-11.0.9.1+1\bin\jps.exe
14864 AdcBridgeApplication
17664 Bootstrap
11876 IgsimulatorApplication
11988 AirWatchSimApplication
22328 Jps
16876 Eclipse
```

Starting cygwin from within a Windows cmd window also prevents me from seeing the full list:

```
C:\>"\tools\java\jdk-11.0.9.1+1\bin\jps.exe"
14864 AdcBridgeApplication
17664 Bootstrap
11876 IgsimulatorApplication
11988 AirWatchSimApplication
21076 Jps
16876 Eclipse

C:\>\tools\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat

wrightm1@NAL10-CP2MP13 ~
$ /cygdrive/c/tools/java/jdk-11.0.9.1+1/bin/jps.exe
12732 Jps
```

I know that jps needs permissions to the running JVMs to list them, presumably starting cygwin from cmd.exe would inherit any permissions from the (working) cmd.exe process.

Comment: have you tried from an Admin user ?

Answer (score 0):

This perception is not just limited to `jps`. I just started a cygwin console on my windows machine:

```
$ ps aux
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     1062    1052    1062      16328  pty0     1147632 22:52:00 /usr/bin/ps
     1051       1    1051      13556  ?        1147632 22:51:56 /usr/bin/mintty
     1052    1051    1052       4512  pty0     1147632 22:51:57 /usr/bin/bash
$
```

While Windows is running, there are definitely a few more processes running but they seem invisible inside cygwin. Whether the reason is a different windows subsystem or something else is beyond my knowledge. But there seems to be a special option to the 'cygwin ps version', as mentioned in https://superuser.com/questions/751688/is-there-a-way-to-show-windows-processes-in-cygwin-constantly

So I guess the `jps` command is simply not cygwin-aware thus it does not come with such an option.